# GitHub not working on Chrome or Windows, but on Firefox

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, bash, git

I am trying to login to GitHub via Chrome (Canary), and it doesn't login at all. 
I can view public repos, but cannot login to my own account. 
I get the message saying **the page isn't working.**

There are no git details in web credentials of Windows. I tried uninstalling git bash, deleting git config file, but it doesn't allow me to connect at all.

The gitbash credentials don't allow to connect as well. I tried two different Wi-Fi, but they don't help as well. I am attaching the screenshot of chrome below.

[image: Chrome page after logging in.]

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Disabled all of them and tried. Still doesn't work.

Comment: are you using a vpn? Also, did you reset chrome to factory default and try again?

Comment: No, I am not. I deleted everything except browsing history.

Comment: click the 3 dot bar in the top right, go to settings, type reset, click restore settings to their original defaults, click reset settings.

Comment: Sounds like a certificate issue.  Chrome and Internet Explorer both use the certificate store of the machine, while Firefox, uses its own certificate store.  Are you connected to a commercial network that would explain the reason you have a certificate issue?

Comment: @Ramhound, no, this is my home network.

Comment: This new behavior or old behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound, the new one. It worked fine on a regular window, but didn't on incognito, just to test I logged out of regular window, now I am unable to go back in.

Comment: What?  I am asking if your inability to log into Github over a SSL connection is something that just recently happened or has always been the case.  The fact Firefox works proves this is likely a certificate issue.  Disable all security software designed to scan HTTPS traffic.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am sorry if I misunderstood your question. No changes has been done to the connection. No new software has been added to my computer. Its been the same for a while.

Comment: @Aijaz - How long have you been unable to log into Github with a browser that uses the system's certificate store?  Have you verified that Chrome believes the certificate is valid?

Comment: @Ramhound, I logged in around 2 weeks back, and tried logging back again yesterday.